# How do I pass a generic USB peripheral from macOS X host to Ubuntu 16.04 x64 guest in VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, usb, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I can do this on my macOS host to see USB devices on commandline

```
ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 21>
  +-o AppleUSBVHCIBCE Root Hub Simulation@80000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000004c7, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 18>
  | +-o iBridge FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)@80200000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000004c9, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (4 ms), retain 18>
  | +-o iBridge ALS@80300000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000004ce, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 11>
  | +-o Headset@80400000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000004d2, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (3 ms), retain 14>
  | +-o iBridge@80100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000004d6, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (3 ms), retain 13>
  | +-o iBridge Display@80600000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000004ed, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 15>
  | +-o iBridge DFR brightness@80700000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000004f1, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 11>
  | +-o Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@80500000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100001fbf, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (11 ms), retain 22>
  +-o AppleUSBXHCI Root Hub Simulation@14000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x100000511, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 9>
  | +-o USB2.0 Hub             @14300000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000cac, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 16>
  |   +-o USB 2.0 Hub@14340000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000ce0, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 18>
  |   | +-o USB Optical Mouse@14343000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000d0e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (4 ms), retain 14>
  |   | +-o USB Keyboard@14344000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000d23, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (5 ms), retain 16>
  |   | +-o PCAN-USB@14341000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100002f33, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 14>
  |   | +-o PCAN-USB@14342000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100002f7a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 14>
  |   +-o Flash Disk      @14330000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100002f8e, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 14>
  +-o AppleUSBXHCI Root Hub Simulation@00000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x100000cc4, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 9>
    +-o USB3.0 Hub             @00100000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x100000cc8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 15>
      +-o Plugable UD-3900@00110000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x10000159d, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (24 ms), retain 31>
```

Now... let's say I want to take a device such as Flash Disk or PCAN-USB and just pass it straight to my Ubuntu 16.04 x64 VirtualBox VM?

I have already done something along these lines to install VirtualBox extension pack on my macOSX host (Mohave 10.14.1)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

With this stuff installed, I set the bus on my VM to USB 2.0 and then tried to get it to detect USB devices plugged into host, but no luck so far.

I noticed in the VirtualBox USB settings I can do a filter... can I somehow passthrough the USB device in such a way? If so, I do not know how to set up the filter correctly based on macOS host. This is what it looks like.

[image: filter]

Has anyone ever been able to just manually set up a USB device that passes from macOS host to linux VM in VirtualBox? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was overthinking this... It turns out I just needed to restart my machine after installing VirtualBox and VB extension pack.

After restarting my host machine then booting my VM from cold boot within VirtualBox, I now see all my USB devices!

To anyone curious about how to get USB info for USB filter settings, it seems this command gives the right output:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

example output:

```
PCAN-USB:

              Product ID: 0x000c
              Vendor ID: 0x0c72
              Version: 54.ff
              Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
              Manufacturer: PEAK-System Technik GmbH
              Location ID: 0x14342000 / 36
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 200
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0

PCAN-USB:

              Product ID: 0x000c
              Vendor ID: 0x0c72
              Version: 54.ff
              Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
              Manufacturer: PEAK-System Technik GmbH
              Location ID: 0x14341000 / 35
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 200
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Comment: Protip to anyone using an Ubuntu VM from macOS host and experiencing performance issues -- My Ubuntu VM was also running extremely slow until I enabled Hardware acceleration in VirtualBox Display options for my VM :)

Comment: Also, this user seems to corraborate my experience
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=87706